# 19.10: `curecoin-qt` wallet installation fails on the last two steps

Tags: software-installation, 19.10, error-handling, debugging, debug

In order to make the most of the  `Folding@Home` project (https://foldingathome.org/covid19/) and fight COVID-19 from our homelabs — tokenwise — I've tried to install the `curecoin-qt` wallet (https://curecoin.net/how-to-install-the-wallet-linux-version/).

However, on the last two steps of the installation process, I receive a following error — if you may:

```
XXXXs@ubuntu:~$ git clone https://github.com/cygnusxi/CurecoinSource.git
Cloning into 'CurecoinSource'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 1201 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 1197
Receiving objects: 100% (1201/1201), 51.31 MiB | 424.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (637/637), done.
XXXXs@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install qt5-default qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev libssl-dev libminiupnpc-dev libdb5.3++-dev dh-make build-essential
[sudo] password for XXXXs: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1).
build-essential set to manually installed.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libboost-atomic1.67-dev libboost-atomic1.67.0 libboost-chrono1.67-dev
  libboost-chrono1.67.0 libboost-date-time1.67-dev libboost-filesystem1.67-dev
  libboost-program-options1.67-dev libboost-program-options1.67.0
  .
  .
  .
  OMITTED A FEW PHASES TO SAVE IN CHARACTER LENGTH
  .
  .
  .

XXXXs@ubuntu:~$ qmake && make
Usage: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake [mode] [options] [files]

QMake has two modes, one mode for generating project files based on
some heuristics, and the other for generating makefiles. Normally you
shouldn't need to specify a mode, as makefile generation is the default
mode for qmake, but you may use this to test qmake on an existing project

Mode:
  -project       Put qmake into project file generation mode
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as files to
                 be built,
                 defaults to *; *; *; *.ts; *.xlf; *.qrc
                 Note: The created .pro file probably will 
                 need to be edited. For example add the QT variable to 
                 specify what modules are required.
  -makefile      Put qmake into makefile generation mode (default)
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as project files to
                 be processed, if skipped qmake will try to find a project
                 file in your current working directory

Warnings Options:
  -Wnone         Turn off all warnings; specific ones may be re-enabled by
                 later -W options
  -Wall          Turn on all warnings
  -Wparser       Turn on parser warnings
  -Wlogic        Turn on logic warnings (on by default)
  -Wdeprecated   Turn on deprecation warnings (on by default)

Options:
   * You can place any variable assignment in options and it will be *
   * processed as if it was in [files]. These assignments will be    *
   * processed before [files] by default.                            *
  -o file        Write output to file
  -d             Increase debug level
  -t templ       Overrides TEMPLATE as templ
  -tp prefix     Overrides TEMPLATE so that prefix is prefixed into the value
  -help          This help
  -v             Version information
  -early         All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right before default_pre.prf
  -before        All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right before [files] (the default)
  -after         All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed after [files]
  -late          All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right after default_post.prf
  -norecursive   Don't do a recursive search
  -recursive     Do a recursive search
  -set <prop> <value> Set persistent property
  -unset <prop>  Unset persistent property
  -query <prop>  Query persistent property. Show all if <prop> is empty.
  -qtconf file   Use file instead of looking for qt.conf
  -cache file    Use file as cache           [makefile mode only]
  -spec spec     Use spec as QMAKESPEC       [makefile mode only]
  -nocache       Don't use a cache file      [makefile mode only]
  -nodepend      Don't generate dependencies [makefile mode only]
  -nomoc         Don't generate moc targets  [makefile mode only]
  -nopwd         Don't look for files in pwd [project mode only]
XXXXs@ubuntu:~$ 
XXXXs@ubuntu:~$
```

Seems like the system doesn't even recognize my final commands (`qmake && make`), but instead returns me with a set of instructions. I don't know what I did wrong, I just followed the instructions (at the top of message).

Cheers!

Comment: After the `git clone` command, you need to `cd` into the new directory and enter the `qmake` command from there.

Comment: @Jos thanks! I feel ashamed for my noobish question, but what directory might that be? :-E

Comment: If you still can reproduce this: if you entered the `git clone` command from `/path/to/X`, you need to do the `qmake` command from `/path/to/X/CurecoinSource`. `/path/to/X` being just an example.

Comment: @Jos I entered the `git clone` command as follows: `git clone https://github.com/cygnusxi/CurecoinSource.git`. I didn't include any additional path to the command, though. Maybe this can be the problem? I also tried to search for the possible destination directory, but didn't spot it. :-( I updated the original question, so please have a new look! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, you entered the clone command from your home directory. So before doing the `qmake`, do `cd CurecoinSource`.